# Is this the right way to implement a return statement in a function? My function won't return a value

Tags: c++, return

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int add(int x, int y) {
    int sum = x + y; 
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    cout << "enter" << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    add(num1, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

`Add()` function does not return `sum` when I run the code. However, when I replace `return sum` with `cout << sum << endl` my program runs well. I am a complete beginner at c++

Comment: You need a variable to assign the return value to. `int s = add(num1, num2);`

Comment: It’s returning a value but your code in main() isn’t using the returned value.  Perhaps you want cout << add(num1, num2) << endl;  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your add function is returning the sum just fine. You just do nothing with it. Consider

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int add(int x, int y) {
  int sum = x + y; 
  return sum;
}
int main() {
  int num1, num2;
  cout << "enter" << endl;
  cin >> num1 >> num2;
  cout << add(num1, num2) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For what it's worth, the version with `cout` in `add` very much does not work fine.

```
int add(int x, int y) {
  int sum = x + y; 
  cout << sum << endl;
}
```

This function exhibits undefined behavior. It declares a return type of non-`void` yet returns nothing. The mere *presence* of this function in your code (even if you never call it) invalidates the whole program and allows the compiler to do as it pleases with your code. Turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall`); it will catch many issues like this for you.